# Python program to execute any other Python program as argument?

Tags: python, subprocess, sys

I am trying to write a Python program to to execute another Python program using `subprocess`. What wrong in this program, and how can I take the other Python program as an argument?

```
import sys
import subprocess
def dorun(args):
   subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '%r'] % args)
dorun()
```

The error is:

```
najeeb@najeeb:~/Desktop/project$ python new-test.py nmap-test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "new-test.py", line 9, in <module>
dorun()
TypeError: dorun() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: `dorun` takes `args` and you aren't passing it anything.

Comment: why not run program your self.and post a write program. if you don not understand what write above please let me now. thanks

Comment: @Arkantus not work i am try already. can your post program then i am try. and thanks

Comment: @dsgdfg guy i am not try write any module. i am try write a program to execute or run other program as a argument and my above code. very simple to under stand what can i am try to do...

Comment: if any one have problem  in my english please let me know

Comment: try on idle : `import subprocess; print  help(subprocess.Popen.__init__)` @NajeebChoudhary who know which app calling from python(perl, bash, C, etc...)  Read subprocess document please! (-1)

Comment: @dsgdfg please read my question....i am execute python program not (c,perl, or etc) please just read what is write above....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless you want to be able to launch several program at one ?

```
import sys
import subprocess
def dorun(args):
   subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, args])
dorun(sys.argv[1])
```